# Export higher order components without 'export default'

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I am using `react-click-outside` to hide dropdown menus if the user clicks outside the menu. Normally, I would export the component like so:

```
export default enhanceWithClickOutside(Dropdown);
```

However, in this case, I want to export the component

```
export { enhancedWithClickOutside(Dropdown) };
```

But that apparently does not work. Is there a way to export using `{}` and also apply the higher order component function?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
export class Dropdown extends React.component {
  ...
}

export const EnhancedDropdown = enhanceWithClickOutside(Dropdown);
```

Somewhere else

```
import { Dropdown, EnhancedDropdown } from 'path/to/Dropdown';
```

Comment: duh, so simple. Thank you.

Comment: What about a react functional component?

Comment: @edbras `export const Dropdown = props => ...`